# Is there a way to restrict a line of code in a do-while loop to only complete once?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, java.util.scanner, do-while

I have a do-while loop in my code, and I have to create a new scanner in it because I'm trying to get the "cursor" back to the top of the file because I had read through the file earlier in the program with a different scanner. The problem is that I'm trying to get the scanner to read the text file line by line, but every time the do-while reiterates it creates a new scanner and the cursor goes back to the top. Is there a way in java to restrict the the creation of the scanner to complete only the first time in the do-while loop, even though the rest of the loop can loop many more times?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: why don't you try to keep that code outside the loop?

Comment: Inside do-while, you can try this: `if(scannerObj ==null) { scannerObj = new Scanner(file); }`, instead of initializing every time. If the instance is already created, don't create again. If this solves your problem, I shall post it as an answer and you can accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You could use a `boolean` flag,

```
boolean runOnce = true;
do {
    // ...
    if (runOnce) {
        // Do this once
        // ...
        runOnce = false;
    }
    // ...
} while (...);
```

Comment: How do I do this, yet still be able to do something like scanner.NextLine(); outside the if statement?

Comment: You make that a different `if` statement. You are not limited to one thing at any point `...` appears above. For better help faster, post some code; we have no real idea what you are doing outside (before or after) anything you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
int count = 0
while(condition is true){
    if(count == 0){
     //this statement will only execute once.
    }
    //main body of while loop
    count++;
}
```

Or

```
boolean executeOnce = true;
    while(condition is true){
        if(executeOnce ){
         //this statement will only execute once.
         executeOnce = false;
        }
        //main body of while loop
    }
```

Comment: I need to do a scanner.nextLine(); several times, but I can't do that if the scanner is in the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative 1:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(...);
do {
    ...
    scanner.nextLine();
    ...
} while (...);
```

Alternative 2:

```
Scanner scanner = null;
do {
    if (scanner == null) {
        scanner = new Scanner(...);
    }
    ...
    scanner.nextLine();
    ...
} while (...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do post your code so it'll be easier to understand the problem you are facing.

To run a specific part of the code only once, all you need to do is put that code snippet in an 'if' statement specific to a value(flag) and change the flag value before you exit the if clause. Use integer or boolean flags for the same.

Integer:

```
do
{
    int flag=1;
    //some code that executes all the time
    if(flag==1)
    {
        //scanner code that executes only once
        flag=0;
    }
    //some code that executes all the time
}
while(condition);
```

Boolean:

```
do
{
    boolean flag=true;
    //some code that executes all the time
    if(flag)
    {
        //scanner code that executes only once
        flag=false;
    }
    //some code which executes all the time
}
while(condition);
```

Considering you need scanner.nextLine() to run more than once, put it in the part of the code which says //some code which executes all the time.
Hope this helps. Good luck!